# 'regex_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, regex, function

I have issues with the funcion regex_replace when I try to apply this funcion I get this error:

```
'regex_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

That's my code.

```
SELECT  dbo.regex_replace(dbo.NOMBRE_EMISOR,'\\\\b( ){2,}\\\\b',' ')
  FROM [dbo].[CFDI_Donatarias_Emisor_Complemento_2018_all]
  where FOLIO_FISCAL = 'A85F29A1-A5A6-450B-9CA0-F9F3CB6D2993'

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'regex_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Comment: And yes, please add a tag for your DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc...)

Comment: @APH brackets arn't valid Oracle database syntax so iam not sure why you are linking to a Oracle "documentation", the topicstarter is most likely using SQL Server when looking into the brackets and error message, not sure why Oracle is mentioned by Salman and you as i didn't see a edit on this question?

Comment: The error message is clear. There is no `regex_replace` function in SQL server. Did you create this function (`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[regex_replace]`)?

Comment: @RaymondNijland just grabbed a link to it, since DBMS wasn't specified.  I think it's generally unusual to use `dbo.` syntax for built-in functions, across systems.

Comment: @APH questions tagged with the `sql` ideally should be answerd/commented as ANSI/ISO SQL standards not database specific comments or documentation links i geuss.. Beside it is pretty clear from the brackets and error message that the topicstarter is using a other database then Oracle database your link will only most likely confuse future readers...

Comment: @APH *" I think it's generally unusual to use dbo. syntax for built-in functions, across systems."* Also there is a chance somebody called a database `dbo` in a other database product other then SQL Server it's is not a positive database product identification which you more or less meant with that statement?

Comment: I have observed that it's very common for users of Microsoft SQL Server to call their product simply "SQL" which confuses most readers, because SQL is the name of a programming language, not a specific RDBMS product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm talking about this function

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

does someone know why donesn't run?